# PYARMOR : the obfuscation write specific character with the wrong encoding. For ex: ° is written Â°

Tags: python, pandas, obfuscation, pyarmor

I use Pyarmor to obfuscate a script which reads a csv file and then looks for the column "Wind Direction (°)". I obtain a key error message "KeyError: 'Wind Direction (Â°)'" when running the obfuscated script.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
Wind_Direction=df['Wind Direction (°)']
```

This does not work when ofbuscated with pyarmor. I changed it using filter method of pandas to avoid looking for the specific character "°" and it worked fine.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
Wind_Direction=df.filter(regex='^Wind Direction',axis=1)
```

I guess this is a problem of encoding between ANSI and UTF-8. Has anyone faced this problem before? It is quite cumbersome to re-write all the code, is there a way to avoid this problem with pyarmor?

Comment: Can't you just scrub the headers so you don't have to deal with non-ascii symbols in the header?

Comment: How are you executing the program to do the obfuscation? There might be a mismatch between the expected locale and the actual locale, you could try setting `LC_ALL=C pyarmor ...`, or something along those lines.

Comment: I 'll try, 'LC_ALL=C...'  thanks. @cs95 It is not a problem with the header but with the line ' Wind_Direction=df['Wind Direction (°)']
' which is translated in 'Wind_Direction=df['Wind Direction (Â°)']' when the code is obfuscated.

Comment: Issue happening in Pyarmor 7.3.6, not sure if still happens in new versions. Did you manage to solve it?